# how to handle nested comment in flex

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I am working on writing a flex scanner for a language supporting nested comment like this:

```
/*
/**/
*/
```

I use to work on ocaml/ocamllex that support recursive calling lex scanner very elegent. But I am now switching to c++/flex, how to handle such nested comment?

Comment: Which solutions have you tried to implement?

Comment: I am currently trying yy_push_state, thanks

Comment: No, I mean that you need to post an [mcve] of what you're trying, otherwise the other community members can't really know what's wrong with what you're trying.

Comment: A state stack would work (but so would a simple counter). What specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: I post my solution below.@AlmightyR @rici

Comment: That solution works fine. FWIW, I just added another solution, possibly less elegant but more efficient. Good luck with your project,.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that only comments can be nested in comments, a stack is a very expensive solution for what could be achieved with a simple counter. For example:

```
%x SC_COMMENT

%%
  int comment_nesting = 0;  /* Line 4 */

"/*"             { BEGIN(SC_COMMENT); }
<SC_COMMENT>{
  "/*"           { ++comment_nesting; }
  "*"+"/"        { if (comment_nesting) --comment_nesting;
                   else BEGIN(INITIAL); }
  "*"+           ; /* Line 11 */
  [^/*\n]+       ; /* Line 12 */
  [/]            ; /* Line 13 */
  \n             ; /* Line 14 */
}
```

Some explanations:

Line 4: Indented lines before the first rule are inserted at the top of the `yylex` function where they can be used to declare and initialize local variables. We use this to initialize the comment nesting depth to 0 on every call to `yylex`. The invariant which must be maintained is that `comment_nesting` is always 0 in the `INITIAL` state.

Lines 11-13: A simpler solution would have been the single pattern `.|\n`. , but that would result in every comment character being treated as a separate subtoken. Even though the corresponding action does nothing, this would have caused the scan loop to be broken and the action switch statement to be executed for every character. So it is usually better to try to match several characters at once.

We need to be careful about <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>*</kbd> characters, though; we can only ignore those asterisks which we are certain are not part of the <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> which terminates the (possibly nested) comment. Hence lines 11 and 12. (Line 12 won't match a sequence of asterisks which is followed by a <kbd>/</kbd> because those will already have been matched by the pattern above, at line 9.) And we need to ignore <kbd>/</kbd> if it is not followed by a <kbd>*</kbd>. Hence line 13.

Line 14: However, it can also be sub-optimal to match too large a token.

First, flex is not optimized for large tokens, and comments can be very large. If flex needs to refill its buffer in the middle of a token, it will retain the open token in the new buffer, and then rescan from the beginning of the token.

Second, flex scanners can automatically track the current line number, and they do so relatively efficiently. The scanner checks for newlines only in tokens matched by patterns which could possibly match a newline. But the entire match needs to be scanned.

We reduce the impact of both of these issues by matching newline characters inside comments as individual tokens. (Line 14, also see line 12) This limits the `yylineno` scan to a single character, and it also limits the expected length of internal comment tokens. The comment itself might be very large, but each line is likely to be limited to a reasonable length, thus avoiding the potentially quadratic rescan on buffer refill.

Comment: that one is much more elegent.

Comment: I get a warning from flex saying line 13 "rule cannot be matched".

Comment: @brianbeuning: There was a typo at line 12 (missing `/`), presumably as a result of my copying the code from a file which used `(*` and `*)` for comments. Sorry; I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @rici I don't understand Lines 9,10                              
"*"+"/"        { if (comment_nesting) --comment_nesting;
                   else BEGIN(INITIAL); }                                                   Say we hit "*/" and say comment_nesting decrements to 0, we don't hit BEGIN(INITIAL) since it is a part of `else`.  My question is: how does this put the lex back in INITIAL state?

Comment: @anand: what don't you understand? The pattern? The nesting count? What `BEGIN` does?

Comment: @rici I got it. I overlooked Line 6 pattern. First time we see `/*` we don't increment `comment_nesting`. Thus once we hit the balancing `*/` in Lines 9, 10 we will hit the `else` part.

Answer (score 5):

I resolve this problem by using yy_push_state , yy_pop_state and start condition like this :

```
%x comment 
%%
"/*" {
  yy_push_state(comment);
}
<comment>{
  "*/" {
    yy_pop_state();
  }

  "/*" {
    yy_push_state(comment);
  }
}
%%
```

In this way, I can handle any level of nested comment.

Comment: It would be worth adding that this requires Bison. I don't believe flex has yy_push/pop without bison.

Comment: @HParker: yes, it does. But you need to specify [`%option stack`](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Options-Affecting-Scanner-Behavior.html#index-stack).