# flex regex use {-} with trailing context

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm dealing with nested comments. I would like to skip as many irrelevant characters as possible at a time. But the pattern `<COMMENT>[^\n]{-}\//\*{-}\*/\/` is illegal. Any suggestion?

**update**:
Given the following case:

```
/**comment* text/**comment text**/comment*/
```

After capturing the first `/*`, it enters `COMMENT` condition. Now I want to eat up as many characters (not `/*` or `*/`) as possible with one match. Since flex choose the longest match, I don't know how to match isolated `*`s (not `*` followed by a `/`) and isolated `/`s. And `\//\*` is not a character class, so we can't compute the difference between it and another class.

Comment: Can you please provide description of regular expression you want to write in _natural language_? For example, such combination `\*{-}\*` is invalid, but even if you modify it to valid `[\*]{-}[\*]`, it doesn't make any sense because it is an empty set... Also note that you cannot match nested comments solely with single regular expression -- they require context-free grammar matcher.

Comment: @gudok Thank you for help, I've updated the question. And sorry for not clarifying it.

Comment: This answer might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34515078/1566221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
%%
"/\*"              { printf("OPEN_COMMENT [%s]\n", yytext); }
"\*/"              { printf("CLOSE_COMMENT [%s]\n", yytext); }
[^*/]+             { printf("TEXT [%s]\n", yytext); }
"\*"               { printf("TEXT [%s]\n", yytext); }
"/"                { printf("TEXT [%s]\n", yytext); }
%%
```

Here longest-match rule *helps* us. Idea is to match free-standing single `*` and `/` symbols separately, while all other text is consumed in bulk (thus not degrading performance).

Result for above example:

```
OPEN_COMMENT [/*]
TEXT [*]
TEXT [comment]
TEXT [*]
TEXT [ text]
OPEN_COMMENT [/*]
TEXT [*]
TEXT [comment text]
TEXT [*]
CLOSE_COMMENT [*/]
TEXT [comment]
CLOSE_COMMENT [*/]
TEXT [
]
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much:)