# Regex clarification on escape sequences with lex

Tags: regex, escaping, lex

I'm creating a lexer.l file that is working as intended except for one part. I have the rule:

`[\(\*.*\*\)] {}`

which I want to make it so when I encounter `(* this is a test *)` in a file, I simply do nothing with it. However when I run `lex lexer.l` I get warning on lines with rules `\(`, `\*`, and `\)` stating that they can never be met. So I guess my question is why would `[\(\*.*\*\)] {}` interfere with `\(` and the others? How can I catch `(* this is a test *)`?

Comment: Note that `(*you will*) have problems (*with this*)`, as your regex will capture everything from `(*you` to `this*)`.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I doubt lex supports lazy quantifiers...

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes thanks, getting rid of the brackets is definitely the solution. why the `?`?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski adding the lazy quantifier `?` works for me in lex, and prevents the issue you originally mentioned

Comment: Oh good, I wasn't aware of that, I thought lex used POSIX regexes.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I believe you are right on that (just started learning lex) but from this resource: http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/prl.html it shows that `?` is valid

Comment: The issue is not whether `?` is valid, but whether `*?` is valid... That's [not the same thing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy). The docs don't seem to mention that.

Comment: ok I understand, I can say for a fact that I am using `\(\*.*?\*\)` and it is working as intended

Comment: @panthor314: Is it? Did you try with an input like `(* a comment *) not a comment (* another comment *)` all on a single line? (f)lex does not implement non-greedy repetition operators (`*?`), so it treats `R*?` as though it were an optional repeated `R` -- which is no different from `R*`.

Comment: oh no, I only tried on a separate line which of course wouldn't catch it

Comment: just tried it out, so on the same line, `not a comment` is caught by the expression when it, for my needs, should not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Languages with the comment syntax `(*…*)` typically allow nested comments, and nested comments cannot easily be recognized by (f)lex because the nesting requires a context-free grammar, and the lexical scanner only implements regular languages.

If your comments do not nest (so that `(* something (* else *)` is a comment, rather than the prefix of a longer comment), then you can use the regular expression

```
[(][*][^*]*[*]+([^*)][^*]*[*]+)*[)]
```

If you do require nested comments, you can use start conditions and a stack (or a simulated stack, as below):

```
%x SC_COMMENT

%%
  int comment_nesting = 0;

"(*"             { BEGIN(SC_COMMENT); }
<SC_COMMENT>{
  "(*"           { ++comment_nesting; }
  "*"+")"        { if (comment_nesting) --comment_nesting;
                   else BEGIN(INITIAL); }
  "*"+           ; 
  [^(*\n]+       ;
  [(]            ; 
  \n             ; 
}
```

That snippet was taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34515078/1566221), with a small adjustment because that answer recognizes nested `/*…*/` comments. A fuller explanation of the code appears there.