# Multi-line match inside literals in Flex

Tags: c, regex, flex-lexer

I am trying to match text inside `%[` and `]%` in single or multiple lines. First thing I tried was:

```
\%\[(.*?)\]\%              return MULTILINE_TEXT;
```

but this works only for single line cases, not for multiple lines. So, I thought I could use `/s`:

```
/\%\[(.*?)\]\%/s           return MULTILINE_TEXT;
```

But flex see this as an invalid rule. The last thing I tried was:

```
\%\[((.*?|\n)*?)\]\%       return MULTILINE_TEXT;
```

which seemed to work, but it doesn't stop at the first `]%`. In the following example:

```
%[ Some text ...
   Some text ... ]%

... other stuff ...

%[ Some more text ...
   Some more text ... ]%
```

flex will return the entire thing as a single token. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `*?` is *not* treated as a non-greedy match by flex.

Flex does support some regex flags, but its syntax is a little different than most regex libraries. For example, you can change the meaning of `.` by setting the `s` flag; the change applies to the region *within* the parentheses (and not following the flag setting, as in PCRE):

```
"%["(?s:.*)"%]"
```

It's more common to see the lex-compatible usage:

```
"%["(.|\n)*"%]"
```

You can also use the `x` flag for slightly more readable regexes:

```
(?xs: "%[" .* "%]" )
```

(The `x` flag does not work in definitions, only in pattern rules.)

Quoted strings (as above) is another (f)lex-specific syntax, which can be more readable than backslash escapes, although backslash escapes also work. But flex does not implement PCRE/Gnu/JS extensions such as `\w` and `\s`.

See [the flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) for a complete guide to flex regexes; it's definitely worth reading if you are used to other regex syntaxes.

You will probably find it disappointing that (f)lex does not support many common regex extensions, including non-greedy matches. That makes it awkward to write patterns for patterns terminated by multiple characters, as with your example. If the delimiters `%[` and `%]` cannot be nested, so that you really want the match to end with the first `%]`, you could use something like this:

```
%\[([^%]|%+[^]])*%+\]   or  (?x: "%[" ( [^%] | %+ [^]] )* %* "%]" )
```

That's a bit hard to read, but it is precise: `%[` followed by any number of repetitions of either a character other than `%` or a sequence of `%` followed by something other than `]`, ending with a sequence of `%` followed by a `]`.

In the above pattern, you need `%+` rather than `%`  to deal with strings like:

```
%[%% text surrounded by percents%%%]
```

A more readable solution which also allows for nested `%[` is to use [start conditions](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Start-Conditions.html). There's a complete example of a very similar solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35048317/1566221).